# Star Wars Beginner Box Set

Tags: star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

I'm 42 years with Emotional and Behavioral issues(Disabled). I have all three Beginner Box Set game. How do I get my niece and her boyfriend to play one of the Star Wars Beginner Box Set games?. 
Backstory: But, she just read the Star Wars Core Rule book and then said: I'm not playing it. If I brought it up again. She'll say: "Ah" to me. 
I have a hunch that she wants to play. But the core rule book is preventing her. She thinks that the Core Rule book for AOR, EOTH and F&D are it.

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to answer this for you, because we don't know your niece and her boyfriend.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE!  Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and see the [help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) center or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance.

Comment: Unfortunately there is simply no possible way we can help you with this particular question. We have no idea who your niece is, why she does or doesn't want to play, or how to go about convincing her to do so (or even if you should).

Comment: Maybe try to ask a different question altogether (here): how can I show the potential of [such_and_such_game] to someone who is not into that game Universe? That would be a question people in this community would be able to answer (maybe).
Also, it's important to remember that different people like different things, and it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

She said "no". When you persisted she avoided the question (presumably to avoid upsetting you).

Respect her boundaries and drop the subject.